# Remove blue outline

Tags: css

I am getting this everytime I press a button, input, etc

[image]

I talk about that light blue border, what should I do to remove it ?

I just try

```
  *:active {
    outline: 0;
  }
```

it doesn't work

Comment: none would be a correct value, else you need to reset  style too; outline:solid 0;

Comment: it is not working that way

Comment: What browser? What operating system?

Comment: @connexo linux, all browsers available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `*:focus`, not `:active`.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer: Show us a demo.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer That should work, also try `*:focus{outline:0 none;}` otherwise It's likely being overwritten, you'll have to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem myself and I have a solution from a project I am currently working on. This could be a solution.

```
your-element:focus,
your-element:active {
    outline: none;
}
```